# .NET 4.7.2 and binding converters

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.7.2

Stuck in a bit of a bind here (pun not intended :) )

A few our our clients updated to Windows 10 Version 1803 which happened to side load .NET 4.7.2.

All seemed ok, but we noticed our WPF grids began to act, well odd. When you clicked on certain cells of the grid, You would only see one value. For Example

If the grid contained the following :

```
Column 1(custom Control) | Column 2 (String) | Column 3 (String)|
          A1             |       B1          |       C1   |
          A2             |       B2          |       C2   |
          A3             |       B3          |       C3   |
```

If you clicked on A3 in Column 1, you would see A3, if you then clicked on A1 in Column 1, you would still see A3.

What I discovered was, in previous .NET versions, clicking on a cell would signal a call to the converter. This would happen on every click of the Cells in Column 1. After 4.7.2 the converter is only called the first time a click is registered in the column, then never called again.

This is how the binding and the converter is set up :

```
// setup binding for this data item
var mbinding = new MultiBinding { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Converter = converter, ValidatesOnExceptions = false, ValidatesOnDataErrors = true };
var binding1 = new Binding(".") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions = false, ValidatesOnDataErrors = true };
var binding2 = new Binding(string.Format("{0}", Adapter.FKKeyCol)) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions = false, ValidatesOnDataErrors = true };
mbinding.Bindings.Add(binding1);
mbinding.Bindings.Add(binding2);
mbinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
if (!editable) mbinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
```

Is there a way to get the converter to be called on that column on every click again?

Comment: More info, please.

Comment: More info, please. 1. Which element+property hosts the MultiBinding?  2. How does that element relate to the Grid?  3. What do you mean by "you would see A3" and where would you see it?  4. How does clicking on a grid cell cause a change in the data model (i.e. the object the DataContext of the hosting element points to)?      Could you possibly build a complete project that illustrates the issue, and share it with me?

Comment: The element that hosts the binding Is a custom Foreign key Lookup tied to a view in a MSSQL database. So when the grid first loads it is shown as a common text field. When the user clicks in the cell (Column 1) The FK lookup is then shown with the value that was in the cell. (a textfield with a clickable magnifying glass).  So what i meant by you will see A3 is :  when you click in column 1 row 3 (A3), you will see the A3 plus a magnifying glass. If you then Click on Column 1 row 2 (A2), instead of seeing A2 and a magnifying glass, you would see A3 again (with the magnifying glass).

Comment: This all worked perfectly in previous versions of .NET (4.6.x) but as soon as 4.7.2 is installed, it no longer works. I am trying to find a way to get the cell to call the convert, but with no success so far.

Comment: Another update on this, I noticed (by looking through some of your other answers Sam that the datacontext is now set to itemdisconnected instead of null now.  Is it possible that the fix for Fixed data corruption arising when a scrolling DataGrid with VirtualizationMode=Recycling. [405066, PresentationFramework.dll, Bug] also caused the convert to not be called now?

Comment: It sounds like this is about DataGrid (not Grid), and the issue arises when user puts a cell into (or out of) edit-mode, where column 1 is a DataGridTemplateColumn whose CellEditingTemplate includes a custom control (ForeighKeyLookup).  Is that right?   That situation would be affected by the 405066 fix, which changes DataContext to DisconnectedItem when the cell leaves edit-mode.  But DataContext should be restored correctly when cell A2 enters edit-mode.   Can you share the column markup (esp. the edit template)?   sambent at microsoft dot com